# Mixin flexbox takes 0 arguments but 1 was passed

Tags: sass, compass

I'm trying to use Flexbox mixins with Compass but ends up with an error.

Adding this mixin creates an error:

```
.flex-wrapper {
    @include display-flex; 
}
```

Error:

> Error: Mixin flexbox takes 0 arguments but 1 was passed on line 94 of
>   c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_flexbox.scss,
>   in 'flexbox' from line 94 of
>   c:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3/stylesheets/compass/css3/_flexbox.scss,
>   in 'display-flex' from line 244 of I:/webdev/site-x/sass/style.scss

Any ideas what the problem is? I've tried to update compass but still problem. I don't it.

Comment: compass-core-1.1.0.alpha.3??

Are you sure that this mixin is the trigger of the error?

Comment: Do you have your own custom `display-flex` mixin?

Comment: No I don't have my own flex mixin at least not as I'm aware of :|